# jQuery Selector for selecting child elements

Tags: jquery

How to change `src` value for an `img` tag that is present only in the first `div` given [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v6eogucp/).

If you notice, first `div`'s `id` value is set to ***dvEA*** and second `div`'s `id` value is set to ***dvEA1***. Inside jQuery script, I'm trying to reference only the first `div` but think I'm not doing it correctly.

Please help if you can.
Thank you.

```html
<div id="dvEA"> 
<a href="">
   <div class="SI" style="margin: 20px;">
   <img src="">
</div>
</a>        
</div>
<div id="dvEA1"> 
<a href="">
   <div class="SI" style="margin: 20px;">
   <img src="">
</div>
</a>        
</div>
```

```js
$("img",".SI","a", "#dvEA").attr('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/Flag_of_Pakistan.svg/250px-Flag_of_Pakistan.svg.png');
```

Comment: Why are you passing multiple arguments to the [$()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/) function? I think you just want `$("#dvEA img")`. See http://jsfiddle.net/khn0zjo4/

Answer (score 0):

To select the `<img>` tag inside `<div id="dvEA">` and change its `src` attribute:

```
$('#dvEA img').attr('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/Flag_of_Pakistan.svg/250px-Flag_of_Pakistan.svg.png');
```